# How to add attributes to ransackable_attributes(:admin)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, ransack

I need to search by `:total_in_stock` in ransack. But it is giving error for undefine total_in_stock.

I tried to troubleshoot this this I came to know only ' ransackable_attributes(:admin) ' attributes can be search.

```
@search = @collection.ransack(params[:q])
@collection = @search.result(distinct: true).page(params[:page]).per(params[:per_page] || Spree::Config[:admin_products_per_page])
```

Here is rails console details.

```
2.5.3 :003 > Spree::ShopVariantPrice

 => Spree::ShopVariantPrice(id: integer, shop_id: integer, variant_id: integer, variant_price_submission_id: integer, currency: string, price: decimal, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, shop_and_price: integer, deleted_at: datetime, track_inventory: boolean, cost_price: decimal, orders_count: integer, stores_count: integer, store_id: integer, total_in_stock: integer, display_on: string, list_price: decimal, available_on: datetime, discontinue_on: datetime)

2.5.3 :004 > Spree::ShopVariantPrice.ransackable_attributes(:admin)
 => ["id", "name", "updated_at", "created_at"]
```

Here is search form written in slim.

```
div data-hook="admin_products_sidebar"
  = search_form_for @search, url: stocks_shop_admin_shop_store_variants_path do |f|
    - locals = {f: f}             
    .row data-hook="admin_products_index_search"
      .col-xs-12.col-md-6
        .form-group
          = f.label :product_name_cont, Spree.t(:name)
          = f.text_field :product_name_cont, size: 15, class: "form-control js-quick-search-target"
      .col-xs-12.col-md-6
         .form-group
          = f.label :variant_total_in_stock_eq, Spree.t(:ariant_total_in_stock_eq)
          = f.number_field :total_in_stock_eq, size: 15, class: 'form-control'
      .col-xs-12.col-md-6
    .form-actions data-hook="admin_products_index_search_buttons"
      = button Spree.t(:search), 'search'
```

I need to get search but its giving following error.

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2001ms (ActiveRecord: 61.6ms)

undefined method `variant_total_in_stock_eq' for #<Ransack::Search:0x00007fbc37d44c48> excluded from capture: No host specified, no public_key specified, no project_id specified

    ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `variant_total_in_stock_eq' for #<Ransack::Search:0x00007fbc37d44c48>):
         9:       .col-xs-12.col-md-6
        10:         .form-group
        11:           = f.label :variant_total_in_stock_eq, Spree.t(:ariant_total_in_stock_eq)
        12:           = f.number_field :varient_total_in_stock_eq, size: 15, class: 'form-control'
        13:       .col-xs-12.col-md-6
        14:         .form-group
        15:           = f.label :variant_total_in_stock_cont, Spree.t(:total_in_stock)

    app/views/spree/shop_admin/shop_variant_prices/_stock_filter.html.slim:12:in `block in _ac7c67bd224087c40f54163747fc855d'
```

Answer (score 2):

I'ad access to only default ransackable attributes of `Spree::ShopVariantPrice`. So, I changed those and added ransackable_attributes for all require models. I'm providing code snippet for above `total_in_stock` case.

`self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
     %w(total_in_stock)
    end`

Remember, I'll ***remove default attributes***. So, you need to all requires model attributes in singulars like model field/column `users` as `user`  like this

`self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
     %w(attribute1 attribute2 attribute3)
    end`